# Is it possible to create a @ArgType with union @Field

Tags: typescript, graphql, union, nestjs, typegraphql

I am attempting to have a input / argtype that can be either a `ContactCreate` or `ContactRead`. But I'm not sure if what I am doing is even possible.

```
import { ContactCreate } from 'contact/ContactCreate'
import { ContactRead } from 'contact/ContactRead'
import { ArgsType, createUnionType, Field } from 'type-graphql'

const ContactObtainUnion = createUnionType({
  name: 'ContactObtain',
  types: () => [ContactCreate, ContactRead],
  resolveType: value => {
    if ('uuid' in value) {
      return ContactRead
    }
    return ContactCreate
  }
})

@ArgsType()
export class ContactObtain {
  @Field(() => ContactObtainUnion)
  contact: typeof ContactObtainUnion
}
```

Is it possible to have a `@Field` that is a union of two different type objects?

Answer (score 2):

GraphQL spec doesn't support input unions yet, so you can't use it in `@ArgsType` nor `@InputType`.

You can read the RFC and discussion on GitHub:
https://github.com/graphql/graphql-spec/issues/627